# encode class to single value not dictionary swift

Tags: swift, encodable

Given the classes:

```
class ComplementApp: Codable{
    let name: String
    let idSpring: String
}

class MasterClass: Encodable{
    let complement: ComplementApp
    ///Other propierties
}
```

I want to get:

```
//Where "Some ID" is the value of complement.idSpring
{
   complement: "Some ID"
   //Plus the other properties
}
```

Not

```
{
   complement: {
      name: "Some Name",
      idSpring: "Some ID"
   }
   //Plus other properties
}
```

Which is the default.
I know that I can do it throw encode function and CodingKeys in MasterClass, but I have like 20 other variables, and I should add 19 extra keys. Can I achieve this implementing CodingKeys in ComplementApp?

Comment: Is it enough if the complement stores all properties in a String manner?

Comment: I mean because for example you could do something like complement: "Some Name|Some ID"

Comment: Mh... nop, I use both properties in different situations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this via a custom `encode(to:)` implementation:

```swift
class ComplementApp: Codable {
    let name: String
    let idSpring: String

    func encode(to coder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = coder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(idSpring)
    }
}
```

Using `singleValueContainer` will result in your object being encoded as a single value instead of a JSON object. And you don't have to touch the outer class.

Comment: Needless to say, `init(from:)` can also be implemented in a similar manner.

Comment: @NicolasMiari ofcourse, however I would advise against it, at least for this particular scenario, as decoding such objects would result  in possible invalid values.

Comment: I think it's perfectly valid in a controlled environment where you **expect** the raw string to be convertible to your custom type. And there's a reason the Codable initializer throws.

Comment: It depends, @NicolasMiari, if you're always encoding to a string, and decoding from a string, then you don't need the extra struct to begin with.

Comment: My case is a bit particular I guess. I'm encoding a strongly typed, opaque "Identifier" struct that internally uses a UUID, but that is an implementation type that client code shouldn't care about. I want to encode/decode it using the `uuidString` valueof the wrapped UUID, so that in the serialized JSON it can act as a key to the objects it identifies.
In any case, thanks for the answer! I wasn't even aware of the existence of `singleValueContainer()`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari yeah, in your case it makes perfect sense to encode/decode to/from different data types. On the other side, the struct from this question has additional fields besides the one being encoded, so also omitting them when decoding makes those fields a litle bit useless.